# Laptop dying during suspend after 2 hours. Suspend/hybrid not working

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, battery, hibernate

So I have a yoga s1 and recently installed ubuntu. Twice now when I close the lid and go into suspend the computer will rapidly drain power from the battery in the span of 2 hours then die shortly after. I've had the computer go into suspend several times by closing the lid and lasted more than 2h without draining nearly as much battery (normal amount; a few percent). Heres the power chart.

[image: power graph]

I tried fixing this by activating suspend/hibernate but the script I used didn't end up working.(Used method 2 from this link http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-use-hybrid-suspend-in-ubuntu.html)

Is there a way to fix the suspend or at least switch to suspend/hibernate so it behaves more like windows/mac when the lid is closed? Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `sudo pm-is-supported --suspend-hybrid; echo $?`? Can your computer suspend to disk and wake up at all? You can try with `sudo pm-hibernate`.